# How is it possible to use forkJoin like concat?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two observables, `observableA` and `observableB`.

I would like to create an observable, which fires once both are completed, but only subscribe to `observableB`, when `observableA` is already finished.

I tried this, but in this case it subscribes to `observableA` and `observableB` in the same time:

```
forkJoin(observableA, observableB).subscribe(([resultA, resultB])=>{
    // ...
})
```

---

It works as expected, if I do it like this:

```
observableA.subscribe(resultA => {
    observableB.subscribe(resultB => {
        // ...
    })
})
```

Comment: Why not fire them off sequentially if sequencing is an issue? Dump these into an array and `shift()` your way through it.

Comment: basically you want observable 1,2 & 3 to execute in sequential order. isn't it ?

Comment: @micronyks I updated the question with an example

Comment: Yeah but it is still sequential execution of each observable.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is probably **mergeMap**, **switchMap** or **ConcatMap**.

```
 observable1$.pipe(
        mergeMap(value=>  observable2$.pipe( 
                mergeMap(value=> observable3$.pipe(
                       map(c=> {return c})))
        ))).subscribe(value=>console.log)
      }
```

Here observable 1 executes first, then 2 & 3. I hope this will help you.
It satisfies your use case too.